# How to pass a parameter to a function present in another view using EventAggregator - backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I saw the post [access function in one view from another in backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708195/access-function-in-one-view-from-another-in-backbone-js). If i want to pass parameter to loadTaskPopup(param) how can i do that ?

```
Backbone.View.prototype.event_aggregator = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

 window.PopupView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, "loadTaskPopup");
      this.model = new PopupModel();
      this.event_aggregator.bind("tasks_popup:show", this.loadTaskPopup);
 },

 loadTaskPopup: function(param) {
    //do something with the parameter
 }
});

window.TaskbarView = Backbone.View.extend({
 loadTaskbarPopup: function() {
  this.event_aggregator.trigger("tasks_popup:show")     //How to pass parameter ?
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it as a second parameter to the trigger:

```
this.event_aggregator.trigger("tasks_popup:show", {
  param1 : "value1",
  param2 : "value2"
});
```

In this case its an object. You'l receive this in `loadTaskPopup`.

```
loadTaskPopup : function(params) {
  // params.param1 and params.param2 will have value1 and value2 respectively here.
}
```

Comment: Is it giving any error ? Coz I have the same code and it works pretty well for me.